# Embed Website in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

is there a way to embed a website in Unity 3D? 
It must be a website instead of a local site. 
I would like to display some live charts, using Grafana, and display them on button click.

The app will be used on iOS.

Thanks

Comment: If you want to show live charts, would it perhaps not be better to just get the data of the charts from the website or web service and then create/draw new charts from this data in Unity3D?

Comment: Also have you tried to search something like "show website Unity3D"? What did you find? Why didn't what you find get you to a solution you could use? If I search this on Google I get many hits, are they all not useful to you?

Comment: One last remark, this kind of question is probably more suitable for http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Hey, pretty much all the results where showing solutions for the other way around, how to display a unity game in a website. So there weren't many useful things. But i suddenly found something like pjvg mentioned. Thanks for your help. Hardcoding would be not useful because like that the charts can be changed any time without needing to change any of the code. But thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a short search I found this [In-App Web Browser](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/57532) in the asset store. It will cost you 5$, but it seems to do what you want and it will save you the time and effort to figure out how to make something like that yourself. It works on both iOS and Android.

Comment: Hey, after putting the question up i found that asset as well and i gave it a shot. Seems to work the way i want it, and saved me heaps of time. But honestly i was wondering why there are almost no other solutions, just this twice rated asset. Thanks for your answer. Problem solved.

Comment: @Cruzad0r I have no clue why there are almost no other solutions. Maybe there's just not a lot of people who want to be able to browse the Web from a Unity application.

Answer (score 2):

I think most people just use the [3D webview asset](https://developer.vuplex.com) for this now since it supports all of the platforms. We use it for login in our Android and Windows games, but it could be used for charts.

Answer (score 1):

This question is old, but for anyone looking today, I've had great success with a plugin called UniWebView. It's a full native browser implementation, so supports all modern HTML/JS/CSS. I've used it a fair amount for mocking up 2D UIs in VR. It works on desktop, iOS and Android.

- Website: https://uniwebview.com
- Unity Asset: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/network/uniwebview-4-175993

**NOTE:** This is a commercial product. I am in no way connected to the authors of this plugin, nor do I receive any compensation or incentive to link to it. I have merely used it successfully on past projects and thought it might be helpful for others.